# implementing onclick in a custom view not working

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am working on an Android application. In my app I am using a custom view. Now I want to implement onclick in that view. But I failed to do that. ontouch is working fine. Please have a look on my code and help me to fix the issue.

```
public class ImagePageCurlView extends View implements OnClickListener{

/** Our Log tag */
private final static String TAG = "PageCurlView";

// Debug text paint stuff
private Paint mTextPaint;
private TextPaint mTextPaintShadow;

/** Px / Draw call */
private int mCurlSpeed;

/** Fixed update time used to create a smooth curl animation */
private int mUpdateRate;

/** The initial offset for x and y axis movements */
private int mInitialEdgeOffset;

/** The mode we will use */
private int mCurlMode;

/** Simple curl mode. Curl target will move only in one axis. */
public static final int CURLMODE_SIMPLE = 0;

/** Dynamic curl mode. Curl target will move on both X and Y axis. */
public static final int CURLMODE_DYNAMIC = 1;

/** Enable/Disable debug mode */
private boolean bEnableDebugMode = false;

/** The context which owns us */
private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

/** Handler used to auto flip time based */
private FlipAnimationHandler mAnimationHandler;

/**
 * Maximum radius a page can be flipped, by default it's the width of the
 * view
 */
private float mFlipRadius;

/** Point used to move */
private Vector2D mMovement;

/** The finger position */
private Vector2D mFinger;

/** Movement point form the last frame */
private Vector2D mOldMovement;

/** Page curl edge */
private Paint mCurlEdgePaint;

/** Our points used to define the current clipping paths in our draw call */
private Vector2D mA, mB, mC, mD, mE, mF, mOldF, mOrigin;

/** Left and top offset to be applied when drawing */
private int mCurrentLeft, mCurrentTop;

/** If false no draw call has been done */
private boolean bViewDrawn;

/** Defines the flip direction that is currently considered */
private boolean bFlipRight;

/** If TRUE we are currently auto-flipping */
private boolean bFlipping;

/** TRUE if the user moves the pages */
private boolean bUserMoves;

/** Used to control touch input blocking */
private boolean bBlockTouchInput = false;

/** Enable input after the next draw event */
private boolean bEnableInputAfterDraw = false;

/** LAGACY The current foreground */
private Bitmap mForeground;

/** LAGACY The current background */
private Bitmap mBackground;

/** LAGACY List of pages, this is just temporal */
public ArrayList<Bitmap> mPages;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> mPages1;

/** LAGACY Current selected page */
private  static int mIndex = 0;

private static int cInt=0;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

String[] example = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.example_array);

/**
 * Inner class used to represent a 2D point.
 */
private class Vector2D {
    public float x, y;

    public Vector2D(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
    }

    public float length() {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    public float lengthSquared() {
        return (x * x) + (y * y);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Vector2D) {
            Vector2D p = (Vector2D) o;
            return p.x == x && p.y == y;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2D reverse() {
        return new Vector2D(-x, -y);
    }

    public Vector2D sum(Vector2D b) {
        return new Vector2D(x + b.x, y + b.y);
    }

    public Vector2D sub(Vector2D b) {
        return new Vector2D(x - b.x, y - b.y);
    }

    public float dot(Vector2D vec) {
        return (x * vec.x) + (y * vec.y);
    }

    public float cross(Vector2D a, Vector2D b) {
        return a.cross(b);
    }

    public float cross(Vector2D vec) {
        return x * vec.y - y * vec.x;
    }

    public float distanceSquared(Vector2D other) {
        float dx = other.x - x;
        float dy = other.y - y;

        return (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
    }

    public float distance(Vector2D other) {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(distanceSquared(other));
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector2D other) {
        return other.x * x + other.y * y;
    }

    public Vector2D normalize() {
        float magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(dotProduct(this));
        return new Vector2D(x / magnitude, y / magnitude);
    }

    public Vector2D mult(float scalar) {
        return new Vector2D(x * scalar, y * scalar);
    }
}

/**
 * Inner class used to make a fixed timed animation of the curl effect.
 */
class FlipAnimationHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ImagePageCurlView.this.FlipAnimationStep();
    }

    public void sleep(long millis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), millis);
    }
}

/**
 * Base
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public ImagePageCurlView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
    ResetClipEdge();
    setOnClickListener(this);
    setClickable(true);
}

/**
 * Construct the object from an XML file. Valid Attributes:
 * 
 * @see android.view.View#View(android.content.Context,
 *      android.util.AttributeSet)
 */
public ImagePageCurlView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);

    // Get the data from the XML AttributeSet
    {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.PageCurlView);

        // Get data
        bEnableDebugMode = a.getBoolean(
                R.styleable.PageCurlView_enableDebugMode, bEnableDebugMode);
        mCurlSpeed = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlSpeed,
                mCurlSpeed);
        mUpdateRate = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_updateRate,
                mUpdateRate);
        mInitialEdgeOffset = a.getInt(
                R.styleable.PageCurlView_initialEdgeOffset,
                mInitialEdgeOffset);
        mCurlMode = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlMode, mCurlMode);

        Log.i(TAG, "mCurlSpeed: " + mCurlSpeed);
        Log.i(TAG, "mUpdateRate: " + mUpdateRate);
        Log.i(TAG, "mInitialEdgeOffset: " + mInitialEdgeOffset);
        Log.i(TAG, "mCurlMode: " + mCurlMode);

        // recycle object (so it can be used by others)
        a.recycle();
    }

    ResetClipEdge();
}

/**
 * Initialize the view
 */
private final void init(Context context) {
    // Foreground text paint
    cInt=0;

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(16);
    mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);

    // The shadow
    mTextPaintShadow = new TextPaint();
    mTextPaintShadow.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaintShadow.setTextSize(16);
    mTextPaintShadow.setColor(0x00000000);

    // Cache the context
    mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);

    // Base padding
    setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

    // The focus flags are needed
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    mMovement = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mFinger = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mOldMovement = new Vector2D(0, 0);

    // Create our curl animation handler
    mAnimationHandler = new FlipAnimationHandler();

    // Create our edge paint
    mCurlEdgePaint = new Paint();
    mCurlEdgePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setShadowLayer(10, -5, 5, 0x99000000);

    // Set the default props, those come from an XML :D
    mCurlSpeed = 200;
    mUpdateRate = 33;
    mInitialEdgeOffset = 20;
    mCurlMode = 1;

    // LEGACY PAGE HANDLING!

    // Create pages

    if(ListingActivity.sFlag){

        ImageActivity.tv.setText(example[ListingActivity.sPosition]);
        // Create some sample images
        mForeground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageActivity.ImageIds[ListingActivity.sPosition]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(0);
        mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageActivity.ImageIds[ListingActivity.sPosition+1]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(1);

    }
    else{

        ImageActivity.tv.setText(example[0]);
        // Create some sample images
        mForeground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageActivity.ImageIds[0]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(0);
        mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                ImageActivity.ImageIds[1]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(1);

    }


}

/**
 * Reset points to it's initial clip edge state
 */
public void ResetClipEdge() {
    // Set our base movement
    mMovement.x = mInitialEdgeOffset;
    mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;
    mOldMovement.x = 0;
    mOldMovement.y = 0;

    // Now set the points
    // TODO: OK, those points MUST come from our measures and
    // the actual bounds of the view!
    mA = new Vector2D(mInitialEdgeOffset, 0);
    mB = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    mC = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), 0);
    mD = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mE = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mF = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mOldF = new Vector2D(0, 0);

    // The movement origin point
    mOrigin = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), 0);
}

/**
 * Return the context which created use. Can return null if the context has
 * been erased.
 */
private Context GetContext() {
    return mContext.get();
}

/**
 * See if the current curl mode is dynamic
 * 
 * @return TRUE if the mode is CURLMODE_DYNAMIC, FALSE otherwise
 */
public boolean IsCurlModeDynamic() {
    return mCurlMode == CURLMODE_DYNAMIC;
}

/**
 * Set the curl speed.
 * 
 * @param curlSpeed
 *            - New speed in px/frame
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if curlspeed < 1
 */
public void SetCurlSpeed(int curlSpeed) {
    if (curlSpeed < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "curlSpeed must be greated than 0");
    mCurlSpeed = curlSpeed;
}

/**
 * Get the current curl speed
 * 
 * @return int - Curl speed in px/frame
 */
public int GetCurlSpeed() {
    return mCurlSpeed;
}

/**
 * Set the update rate for the curl animation
 * 
 * @param updateRate
 *            - Fixed animation update rate in fps
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if updateRate < 1
 */
public void SetUpdateRate(int updateRate) {
    if (updateRate < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "updateRate must be greated than 0");
    mUpdateRate = updateRate;
}

/**
 * Get the current animation update rate
 * 
 * @return int - Fixed animation update rate in fps
 */
public int GetUpdateRate() {
    return mUpdateRate;
}

/**
 * Set the initial pixel offset for the curl edge
 * 
 * @param initialEdgeOffset
 *            - px offset for curl edge
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if initialEdgeOffset < 0
 */
public void SetInitialEdgeOffset(int initialEdgeOffset) {
    if (initialEdgeOffset < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "initialEdgeOffset can not negative");
    mInitialEdgeOffset = initialEdgeOffset;
}

/**
 * Get the initial pixel offset for the curl edge
 * 
 * @return int - px
 */
public int GetInitialEdgeOffset() {
    return mInitialEdgeOffset;
}


public void SetCurlMode(int curlMode) {
    if (curlMode != CURLMODE_SIMPLE && curlMode != CURLMODE_DYNAMIC)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid curlMode");
    mCurlMode = curlMode;
}


public int GetCurlMode() {
    return mCurlMode;
}

/**
 * Enable debug mode. This will draw a lot of data in the view so you can
 * track what is happening
 * 
 * @param bFlag
 *            - boolean flag
 */
public void SetEnableDebugMode(boolean bFlag) {
    bEnableDebugMode = bFlag;
}

/**
 * Check if we are currently in debug mode.
 * 
 * @return boolean - If TRUE debug mode is on, FALSE otherwise.
 */
public boolean IsDebugModeEnabled() {
    return bEnableDebugMode;
}

/**
 * @see android.view.View#measure(int, int)
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int finalWidth, finalHeight;
    finalWidth = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    finalHeight = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(finalWidth, finalHeight);
}

/**
 * Determines the width of this view
 * 
 * @param measureSpec
 *            A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text
        result = specSize;
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Determines the height of this view
 * 
 * @param measureSpec
 *            A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = specSize;
    }
    return result;
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!bBlockTouchInput) {

        // Get our finger position
        mFinger.x = event.getX();
        mFinger.y = event.getY();
        int width = getWidth();

        // Depending on the action do what we need to
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mOldMovement.x = mFinger.x;
            mOldMovement.y = mFinger.y;

            // If we moved over the half of the display flip to next
            if (mOldMovement.x > (width >> 1)) {
                mMovement.x = mInitialEdgeOffset;
                mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;

                // Set the right movement flag
                bFlipRight = true;

            } else {
                // Set the left movement flag
                bFlipRight = false;

                // go to next previous page
                previousView();

                // Set new movement
                mMovement.x = IsCurlModeDynamic() ? width << 1 : width;
                mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            bUserMoves = false;
            bFlipping = true;
            FlipAnimationStep();


            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            bUserMoves = true;

            // Get movement
            mMovement.x -= mFinger.x - mOldMovement.x;
            mMovement.y -= mFinger.y - mOldMovement.y;
            mMovement = CapMovement(mMovement, true);

            // Make sure the y value get's locked at a nice level
            if (mMovement.y <= 1)
                mMovement.y = 1;

            // Get movement direction
            if (mFinger.x < mOldMovement.x) {
                bFlipRight = true;
            } else {
                bFlipRight = false;
            }

            // Save old movement values
            mOldMovement.x = mFinger.x;
            mOldMovement.y = mFinger.y;

            // Force a new draw call
            DoPageCurl();
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        }

    }

    // TODO: Only consume event if we need to.
    return true;
}


private Vector2D CapMovement(Vector2D point, boolean bMaintainMoveDir) {
    // Make sure we never ever move too much
    if (point.distance(mOrigin) > mFlipRadius) {
        if (bMaintainMoveDir) {
            // Maintain the direction
            point = mOrigin.sum(point.sub(mOrigin).normalize()
                    .mult(mFlipRadius));
        } else {
            // Change direction
            if (point.x > (mOrigin.x + mFlipRadius))
                point.x = (mOrigin.x + mFlipRadius);
            else if (point.x < (mOrigin.x - mFlipRadius))
                point.x = (mOrigin.x - mFlipRadius);
            point.y = (float) (Math.sin(Math.acos(Math.abs(point.x
                    - mOrigin.x)
                    / mFlipRadius)) * mFlipRadius);
        }
    }
    return point;
}

/**
 * Execute a step of the flip animation
 */
public void FlipAnimationStep() {
    if (!bFlipping)
        return;

    int width = getWidth();

    // No input when flipping
    bBlockTouchInput = true;

    // Handle speed
    float curlSpeed = mCurlSpeed;
    if (!bFlipRight)
        curlSpeed *= -1;

    // Move us
    mMovement.x += curlSpeed;
    mMovement = CapMovement(mMovement, false);

    // Create values
    DoPageCurl();

    // Check for endings :D
    if (mA.x < 1 || mA.x > width - 1) {
        bFlipping = false;
        if (bFlipRight) {
            // SwapViews();
            nextView();
        }
        ResetClipEdge();

        // Create values
        DoPageCurl();

        // Enable touch input after the next draw event
        bEnableInputAfterDraw = true;
    } else {
        mAnimationHandler.sleep(mUpdateRate);
    }

    // Force a new draw call
    this.invalidate();
}

/**
 * Do the page curl depending on the methods we are using
 */
private void DoPageCurl() {
    if (bFlipping) {
        if (IsCurlModeDynamic())
            doDynamicCurl();
        else
            doSimpleCurl();

    } else {
        if (IsCurlModeDynamic())
            doDynamicCurl();
        else
            doSimpleCurl();
    }
}

/**
 * Do a simple page curl effect
 */
private void doSimpleCurl() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    // Calculate point A
    mA.x = width - mMovement.x;
    mA.y = height;

    // Calculate point D
    mD.x = 0;
    mD.y = 0;
    if (mA.x > width / 2) {
        mD.x = width;
        mD.y = height - (width - mA.x) * height / mA.x;
    } else {
        mD.x = 2 * mA.x;
        mD.y = 0;
    }

    // Now calculate E and F taking into account that the line
    // AD is perpendicular to FB and EC. B and C are fixed points.
    double angle = Math
            .atan((height - mD.y) / (mD.x + mMovement.x - width));
    double _cos = Math.cos(2 * angle);
    double _sin = Math.sin(2 * angle);

    // And get F
    mF.x = (float) (width - mMovement.x + _cos * mMovement.x);
    mF.y = (float) (height - _sin * mMovement.x);

    // If the x position of A is above half of the page we are still not
    // folding the upper-right edge and so E and D are equal.
    if (mA.x > width / 2) {
        mE.x = mD.x;
        mE.y = mD.y;
    } else {
        // So get E
        mE.x = (float) (mD.x + _cos * (width - mD.x));
        mE.y = (float) -(_sin * (width - mD.x));
    }
}

/**
 * Calculate the dynamic effect, that one that follows the users finger
 */
private void doDynamicCurl() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    // F will follow the finger, we add a small displacement
    // So that we can see the edge
    mF.x = width - mMovement.x + 0.1f;
    mF.y = height - mMovement.y + 0.1f;

    // Set min points
    if (mA.x == 0) {
        mF.x = Math.min(mF.x, mOldF.x);
        mF.y = Math.max(mF.y, mOldF.y);
    }

    // Get diffs
    float deltaX = width - mF.x;
    float deltaY = height - mF.y;

    float BH = (float) (Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) / 2);
    double tangAlpha = deltaY / deltaX;
    double alpha = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX);
    double _cos = Math.cos(alpha);
    double _sin = Math.sin(alpha);

    mA.x = (float) (width - (BH / _cos));
    mA.y = height;

    mD.y = (float) (height - (BH / _sin));
    mD.x = width;

    mA.x = Math.max(0, mA.x);
    if (mA.x == 0) {
        mOldF.x = mF.x;
        mOldF.y = mF.y;
    }

    // Get W
    mE.x = mD.x;
    mE.y = mD.y;

    // Correct
    if (mD.y < 0) {
        mD.x = width + (float) (tangAlpha * mD.y);
        mE.y = 0;
        mE.x = width + (float) (Math.tan(2 * alpha) * mD.y);
    }
}

/**
 * Swap between the fore and back-ground.
 */
@Deprecated
private void SwapViews() {
    Bitmap temp = mForeground;
    mForeground = mBackground;
    mBackground = temp;
}

/**
 * Swap to next view
 */
private void nextView() {


    int foreIndex = mIndex + 1;

    if (foreIndex >= ImageActivity.ImageIds.length) {
        foreIndex = 0;
    }

    ImageActivity.tv.setText(example[foreIndex]);

    int backIndex = foreIndex + 1;
    if (backIndex >= ImageActivity.ImageIds.length) {
        backIndex = 0;
    }
    mIndex = foreIndex;
    setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);
}

/**
 * Swap to previous view
 */
private void previousView() {
    int backIndex = mIndex;
    int foreIndex = backIndex - 1;
    if (foreIndex < 0) {
        foreIndex = ImageActivity.ImageIds.length - 1;
    }

    ImageActivity.tv.setText(example[foreIndex]);

    mIndex = foreIndex;
    setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);
}

/**
 * Set current fore and background
 * 
 * @param foreground
 *            - Foreground view index
 * @param background
 *            - Background view index
 */
private void setViews(int foreground, int background) {
    mForeground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            ImageActivity.ImageIds[foreground]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(foreground);
    mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            ImageActivity.ImageIds[background]);//HomeActivity.mPages.get(background);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// Drawing methods
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Always refresh offsets
    mCurrentLeft = getLeft();
    mCurrentTop = getTop();

    // Translate the whole canvas
    // canvas.translate(mCurrentLeft, mCurrentTop);

    // We need to initialize all size data when we first draw the view
    if (!bViewDrawn) {
        bViewDrawn = true;
        onFirstDrawEvent(canvas);
    }

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Curl pages
    // DoPageCurl();

    // TODO: This just scales the views to the current
    // width and height. We should add some logic for:
    // 1) Maintain aspect ratio
    // 2) Uniform scale
    // 3) ...
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.left = 0;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.bottom = getHeight();
    rect.right = getWidth();

    // First Page render
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // Draw our elements
    drawForeground(canvas, rect, paint);
    drawBackground(canvas, rect, paint);
    drawCurlEdge(canvas);

    // Draw any debug info once we are done
    if (bEnableDebugMode)
        drawDebug(canvas);

    // Check if we can re-enable input
    if (bEnableInputAfterDraw) {
        bBlockTouchInput = false;
        bEnableInputAfterDraw = false;
    }

    // Restore canvas
    // canvas.restore();
    this.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * Called on the first draw event of the view
 * 
 * @param canvas
 */
protected void onFirstDrawEvent(Canvas canvas) {

    mFlipRadius = getWidth();

    ResetClipEdge();
    DoPageCurl();
}

/**
 * Draw the foreground
 * 
 * @param canvas
 * @param rect
 * @param paint
 */
private void drawForeground(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mForeground, null, rect, paint);

    // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D
    // there is no page number 0 hehe)
    drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);
}

/**
 * Create a Path used as a mask to draw the background page
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Path createBackgroundPath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    path.lineTo(mB.x, mB.y);
    path.lineTo(mC.x, mC.y);
    path.lineTo(mD.x, mD.y);
    path.lineTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    return path;
}

/**
 * Draw the background image.
 * 
 * @param canvas
 * @param rect
 * @param paint
 */
private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint) {
    Path mask = createBackgroundPath();

    // Save current canvas so we do not mess it up
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(mask);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, null, rect, paint);

    // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D
    // there is no page number 0 hehe)
    drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);

    canvas.restore();
}

/**
 * Creates a path used to draw the curl edge in.
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Path createCurlEdgePath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    path.lineTo(mD.x, mD.y);
    path.lineTo(mE.x, mE.y);
    path.lineTo(mF.x, mF.y);
    path.lineTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    return path;
}

private void drawCurlEdge(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = createCurlEdgePath();
    canvas.drawPath(path, mCurlEdgePaint);
}

private void drawPageNum(Canvas canvas, int pageNum) {
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    String pageNumText = "- " + pageNum + " -";
    drawCentered(canvas, pageNumText,
            canvas.getHeight() - mTextPaint.getTextSize() - 5, mTextPaint,
            mTextPaintShadow);
}

public static void drawTextShadowed(Canvas canvas, String text, float x,
        float y, Paint textPain, Paint shadowPaint) {
    canvas.drawText(text, x - 1, y, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y + 1, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x + 1, y, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y - 1, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, textPain);
}

public static void drawCentered(Canvas canvas, String text, float y,
        Paint textPain, Paint shadowPaint) {
    float posx = (canvas.getWidth() - textPain.measureText(text)) / 2;
    drawTextShadowed(canvas, text, posx, y, textPain, shadowPaint);
}

/**
 * Draw debug info
 * 
 * @param canvas
 */
private void drawDebug(Canvas canvas) {
    float posX = 10;
    float posY = 20;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, getWidth(), paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, getWidth(), paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLine(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mMovement.x, mMovement.y, paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mMovement.x, mMovement.y, paint);

    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "A", mA, Color.RED, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "B", mB, Color.GREEN, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "C", mC, Color.BLUE, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "D", mD, Color.CYAN, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "E", mE, Color.YELLOW, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "F", mF, Color.LTGRAY, posX, posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "Mov", mMovement, Color.DKGRAY, posX,
            posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "Origin", mOrigin, Color.MAGENTA, posX,
            posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas, "Finger", mFinger, Color.GREEN, posX,
            posY);


}

private float debugDrawPoint(Canvas canvas, String name, Vector2D point,
        int color, float posX, float posY) {
    return debugDrawPoint(canvas, name + " " + point.toString(), point.x,
            point.y, color, posX, posY);
}

private float debugDrawPoint(Canvas canvas, String name, float X, float Y,
        int color, float posX, float posY) {
    mTextPaint.setColor(color);
    drawTextShadowed(canvas, name, posX, posY, mTextPaint, mTextPaintShadow);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawPoint(X, Y, paint);
    return posY + 15;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("testing click");


}





}
```

Its working now When I add onclicklistener in every block and change return true to false in ontouchevent. But now ontouch is not working because i change its return type. How can I fix it?

Comment: What's your target api level?

Comment: Please don't post excessively long code snippets (or entire applications) - just post what is causing your errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onTouchEvent` is defined in the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and you are just overriding it. Your `setOnTouchListener(this);` has nothing to do with it.

Add in all constructors the `setOnClickListener(this);` and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you for the reply. If I just add setOnClickListener(this); in all constructors of my view, then my onclick() method will call . right???

Comment: I added setOnClickListener(this); in every constructors, then also onclick is not called.:(

Comment: The `setOnClickListener(this)` must be placed in a block of code that you know will be executed. Also you should use Log.d(...) instead of System.out.println(...)

Comment: Its working now When I add onclicklistener in every block and change return true to false in ontouchevent. But now ontouch is not working because i change its return type. How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every block" but I think you need to place it in the one block that is always executed. Try returning super.onTouchevent(event) in your onTouchEvent code

Comment: Try returning super.onTouchevent(event) in your onTouchEvent code

Comment: @ JScoobyCed.. Thank you very much. Returning super.onTouchevent(event) solved my issue..:)

Comment: Answer makes no sense.